# Group by multiple column, fill left join data on group when join condition failed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the two following tables:

**test_data:**

| test_id | question_id | answer_id | valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | q1 | a1 | true |
| t1 | q1 | a2 | true |
| t1 | q1 | a3 | false |
| t1 | q1 | a4 | false |
| t1 | q2 | a5 | true |
| t1 | q2 | a6 | false |
| t1 | q3 | a7 | true |
| t1 | q3 | a8 | false |
| t1 | q3 | a9 | false |
| t2 | q4 | a10 | false |
| t2 | q4 | a11 | false |
| t2 | q4 | a12 | true |

**user_answers:**

| user_id | test_id | question_id | given_answer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | t1 | q1 | a1 |
| u1 | t1 | q1 | a3 |
| u1 | t1 | q2 | a6 |
| u1 | t2 | q4 | a10 |
| u2 | t2 | q4 | a12 |

I want to get the following result:

| user_id | test_id | question_correct_count | question_wrong_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | t1 | 1 | 2 |
| u1 | t2 | 0 | 1 |
| u2 | t1 | 0 | 3 |
| u2 | t2 | 1 | 0 |

My idea was to `test_data left join user_answers` and then proceeed with `group by user_id, test_id` and do all the conditional counting.

But an **user is not required** to answer all the questions so I have `NULL` in the `user_id` column for some questions. Missing tests or non answered question are are to be treated as wrong. For example:

- `u2` did not completed `t1`, so `t1` for `u2` hs 3 wrong question. The test contains 3 questions.
- `u1` did not answer `q3` of `t1` so `q3` count as wrong.
- `u1` did answer `a1` and `a3` in `q1` but even if `a1` is correct he also picked `a3` instead of `a2`, so this is wrong so `q1` is also wrong.
- `u1` chosed the wrong answer for `q4` of `t2` so his `t2` has 1 wrong question (the test has only one question)

How to fill the missing data for each user in the `user_answers` table?

Comment: On the desired output, u2 - t1 - 0 - 3, but u2 did not give any answer for t1, and has 3 wrongs?

Comment: Also, u1 -  t1 - 1 - 2, but u1 for t1 has 2 correct answers and 1 wrong answer. You need to edit the question.

Comment: I've updated the question, I've added some explaination of the validation logic.

Comment: Now, more clearer, but still u1 answered q2 of t1 so, u1 - t2 - 2 - 2, should be correct one right?

Comment: I've updated the input data tables hoping it is more clear.
u1 answered q2 of t2 so for that test he has 1 wrong question; the test contains only a single question (q4).

Comment: Still not clear/has errors. "u1 did answer a1 and a3 in q1 but even if a1 is correct he also picked a3 instead of a2, so this is wrong so q1 is also wrong." u1 answered q2 in t1 as a6 and a6 is wrong for q2 in t1. So for u1 q1 is wrong, q2 is wrong and q3 is wrong. How did you get 1 correct and 2 wrong answer? Your data and expected result is wrong! Also, what would happen if u1 just answer q1 in t1 as a1? Because, in t1 question q1 has multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
with  res0 as ( -- test results
select a.user_id,a.test_id,a.question_id,a.given_answer_id,t.valid
from user_answers a
inner join test_data t on t.test_id=a.test_id and t.question_id=a.question_id
   and t.answer_id=given_answer_id 
)
,res as (-- one answer for one question
select a.user_id,a.test_id,a.question_id
  ,case when sum(case when valid='false' then -1 else 0 end)<0 then 'false' 
  else 'true' end valid
from res0 a
group by user_id,test_id,a.question_id
)
,resg as( -- result grouped
  select user_id,test_id
    ,sum(case when valid='true' then 1 else 0 end)valid_qty
    ,sum(case when valid='false' then 1 else 0 end)notvalid_qty
  from res
  group by user_id,test_id
)
,tests as( -- all tests and question count for every test
select test_id
  ,count(distinct question_id) test_question_qty
from test_data
group by test_id
)
select u.user_id,t.test_id
  ,coalesce(valid_qty,0) question_correct_count
  ,coalesce(test_question_qty,0)-coalesce(valid_qty,0) question_wrong_count
  ,test_question_qty,coalesce(valid_qty,0) valid_qty
  ,coalesce(notvalid_qty,0) notvalid_qty
  ,coalesce(test_question_qty,0)-coalesce(valid_qty,0)
       -coalesce(notvalid_qty,0) as notanswered_qty
from  (select distinct user_id from user_answers) u
left join tests t on 1=1 
left join resg g on g.user_id=u.user_id and t.test_id=g.test_id
;
```

| user_id | test_id | correct_count | wrong_count | test_question_qty | valid | notvalid | notanswered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | t1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| u1 | t2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| u2 | t1 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| u2 | t2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |